# SecurityTokenValidated Identity gets lost

Tags: oauth-2.0, owin, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get an access token in SecurityTokenValidated event , and after I get the access token I save it in  a claim. The problem is that when I try to access that claim it doesn't exists anymore.

The SecurityTokenValidated code is this:

```
  public static async Task<Task> SecurityTokenValidated(SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
        string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
        string source = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExchangeOnlineId"];

        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance, false);
        var credentials = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        var appRedirectUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase + "/";
        var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(context.ProtocolMessage.Code, new Uri(appRedirectUrl), credentials, source);
        var accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;
        var applicationUserIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.OwinContext.Authentication.User.Identity);
        applicationUserIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("AccessToken", accessToken));
        context.OwinContext.Authentication.User.AddIdentity(applicationUserIdentity);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

and I try to access it like this:

```
var accessToken =((ClaimsPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User).FindFirst("AccessToken").Value;
```

Update:
It turns out we have some code that overrides the HttpContext.Current.User. I did some changes on that code like this:

```
 var claims = ((ClaimsPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User).Claims;
            var newPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(domainUserName), null);
            ((ClaimsIdentity)newPrincipal.Identity).AddClaims(claims);
            HttpContext.Current.User = newPrincipal;
```

But no luck. I can get the claims just fine, but I can't see them on the newPrincipal...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems the problem was how I was accessing them. This doesn't work:

```
var accessToken =((ClaimsPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User).FindFirst("AccessToken").Value;
```

While this does:

```
var accessToken =((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).FindFirst("AccessToken").Value;
```